# Searching Multi-Column on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two problems. First being, in the code below I am trying to search for words in order to find the exact object quicker, but every time, I start the program it starts off blank until I put a character and erase and then everything in the list box appears. I thought taking away `Me.allitems.Clear`would fix it, but when I tried to delete the `Me.allitems.Clear`, it does not affect it.

My second problem is that since I have two columns, I need it to search both columns for the respective word. I tried duplicating the bottom code

```
If Left(itemsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, a) = Left(Me.searchbox.Text, a) Then
Me.allitems.AddItem itemsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
Me.allitems.List(allitems.ListCount - 1, 1) = itemsheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
```

and adding a 2 to it, but that didn't work.

The whole code:

```
Private Sub searchbox_Change()

Dim itemsheet As Worksheet
Set itemsheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6)

Dim i As Long

Me.searchbox.Text = StrConv(Me.searchbox.Text, vbProperCase)
Me.allitems.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(itemsheet.Range("A:B"))
    a = Len(Me.searchbox.Text)
    If Left(itemsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, a) = Left(Me.searchbox.Text, a) Then
        Me.allitems.AddItem itemsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Me.allitems.List(allitems.ListCount - 1, 1) = itemsheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Any advice?

**EDIT:**
I found that the first problem is actually when adding the items into the listbox in this line:

```
.List(i, 0) = itemnum
.List(i, 1) = Description
i = i + 1
```

This is the adding the info in the listbox code:

```
For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("A2:A3400")
    With Me.allitems
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
        .AddItem itemname.Value
        .List(i, 0) = itemnum
        .List(i, 1) = Description
        i = i + 1
    End With
Next itemname
```

So specifically the i is the problem, but I need it to add the column

This is how it looks when I first open it up

[image]

When I put a character and then  erase this appears

[image]

This is how it's suppose to look like and I should be able to add it:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those, who were wondering how to fix this type, it was pretty easy, just add an Or for the columns like this :

`If Left(itemsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, a) = Left(Me.searchbox.Text, a) Or Left(itemsheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, a) = Left(Me.searchbox.Text, a) Then`

As for my first problem, still looking for , but for now I have it doing `Do Until loop =""`
Which is only showing all of the them in one column